# Combining python turtle and tkinter`

Tags: python, tkinter, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I need to combine python turtle and tkinter for tic tac toe game, I looked at some sites and tried, but it didn't worked as I imagine, so I need help.
Code:

```
from turtle import *
from circle import Tac
from cross import Tic
from tkinter import *

screen = Screen()
screen.title("Tic Tac Toe")
screen.setup(width=300, height=500)
tim = Turtle()
board = "board.gif"
screen.addshape(board)
img_turtle = Turtle()
img_turtle.shape(board)
screen.listen()
tim.penup()
tim.seth(0)
```

Code I want to add:

```
button1 = Button(text="button", command=tic.one)
button1.place(x=-70, y=42)
```

Comment: This is making it more complicated than it needs to be. You could have all your code in `tkinter`, and not use `turtle` at all. If you use `tkinter`'s `Canvas` widget, you can easily draw a tic tac toe board, and get click events from the user for placing game pieces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python turtle is designed to operate either *standalone* or *embedded* in a larger tkinter program.  You're trying to use the standalone interface in an embedded situation.  Below is my rework of what I would have expected your code to look like.  Since you didn't provide a runnable example, this is an incomplete sketch:

```
from tkinter import *
from turtle import RawTurtle, TurtleScreen
from circle import Tac
from cross import Tic

BOARD = "board.gif"

root = Tk()
root.title("Tic Tac Toe")

canvas = Canvas(root, width=300, height=500)
canvas.pack(side=LEFT)

screen = TurtleScreen(canvas)
screen.addshape(BOARD)

tim = RawTurtle(screen)
tim.penup()

img_turtle = RawTurtle(screen)
img_turtle.shape(BOARD)

button = Button(root, text="button", command=tic.one)
button.pack()

screen.mainloop()
```